# Get position (lat,lng) of already created markers in google map

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, google-maps, methods

Here i have a function route(); and this function create a direction between two places nad create a two markers from startPoint and from endPoint. All is ok, but how here I can write a function that will return me a lat,lng from start point and lat,lng from end point without to use geocoding here, becouse markers are already created in this function

FUNCTION route(); code:

```
function route() {
  // Clear any previous route boxes from the map
  clearBoxes();

  // Convert the distance to box around the route from miles to km
  distance = parseFloat(document.getElementById("distance").value) * 1.609344;

  var request = {
    origin: document.getElementById("from").value,
    destination: document.getElementById("to").value,
    travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
  }

  // Make the directions request
  directionService.route(request, function(result, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);

      // Box around the overview path of the first route
      var path = result.routes[0].overview_path;
      var boxes = routeBoxer.box(path, distance);
      // alert(boxes.length);
      drawBoxes(boxes);
      findPlaces(boxes,0);
    } else {
      alert("Directions query failed: " + status);
    }
  });
}
```

So I need in some variables etc. var startPoint = [lat,lng]; var endPoint = [lat,lng] to get here becouse I dont want to use geocoding request again, becouse here are markers and his coordinates position already created...

I want to getPosition of two markers and how I can do that?

Comment: DEMO and FULL CODE example: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/routeboxer/examples/routeboxer-v3.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parse the location out of the [DirectionsResult](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#DirectionsResult)

```
if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
  directionsRenderer.setDirections(result);
  var route = response.routes[0];
  startLocation = new Object();
  endLocation = new Object();

  var path = response.routes[0].overview_path;
  var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
  for (i=0;i<legs.length;i++) {
    if (i == 0) { 
      startLocation.latlng = legs[i].start_location;
      startLocation.address = legs[i].start_address;
    }
    endLocation.latlng = legs[i].end_location;
    endLocation.address = legs[i].end_address;
  }
  // ... rest of your code to display the route ...
```

[working example that does that (and renders the polyline and creates markers)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Comment: Yes but how I can use startLocation , endLocation in other functions now/??

Comment: Maybe you should ask the question you want answered then.  Or provide the code _you_ wrote that is going to use the values.

Comment: I though my answer was pretty clear on where to put the code in the example you provided.  What problem did you have when you did that? Where are you attempting to use those locations? What do you need them for?

Comment: What happened to // ... rest of your code to display the route ...`

Comment: Without that code it will do exactly what it is doing (parsing the data for the markers out of the response, but not doing anything with that, not displaying the route or changing the zoom, because your removed that code...)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37674/discussion-between-marco-jordan-and-geocodezip)

Comment: http://jsbin.com/UMebuNi/3/edit so how i can use start and end point now i other functions, how i can call it???

Comment: Also I try to call startLocation in function but doesnt work, also doesnt work console.log(startLocation); why that? Where I wrong?

Comment: The DirectionsService is asynchronous, you need to use those variables inside the callback routine (or on a user action after the route has been processed and displayed)

Comment: You haven't clearly stated _what_ you need those variables for.  My "working example" in my answer uses those values to place markers on the map.

Comment: etc. after User click on div ID='button' to show a coordinates from start and from endPoint ....

Comment: also I need this variables to use in other function

Comment: I try with console.log(startLocation.latlng);
but i get error